# Decidability of the satisfiability of an infinite set of propositional formulas.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, computability

If $\Gamma$ is an infinite set of propositional formulas, is the statement: "$\Gamma$ is satisfiable" decidable?

Here, $\Gamma$ is satisfiable means that there exists a truth function $v$ such that $v(\gamma)=$ True for all $\gamma \in \Gamma$.

Here are some facts I know:

- The set of all propositional formulas is countable (our alphabet is either finite or countable), so $\Gamma$ is countable.
- The compactness theorem tells us that $\Gamma$ is satisfiable if and only if every finite subset, say $\Delta$, of $\Gamma$ is satisfiable.
- The set of all finite subsets of a countable set is itself countable, and the satisfiability of any finite set of propositional formulas is a decidable question (we can use truth tables).

I was only able to prove:

"$\Gamma$ is unsatisfiable" is semi-decidable.

$\Gamma = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \Delta_n$, where each $\Delta_n$ is finite. We define a procedure $P$ that for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$ checks whether $\Delta_i$ is satisfiable using the truth-table method. If $\Delta_i$ is satisfiable then it iterates the process with $\Delta_{i+1}$. If $\Delta_i$ is unsatisfiable it halts and returns unsatisfiable.

Comment: Not that I know the answer, but: Seems to me you need to assume that $\Gamma$ is recursive, or recursively enumerable or something, before the question even quite makes sense. Otherwise exactly what would the _input_ to the decision procedure be?

Comment: Hmm. Of course, taking the question _literally_, the answer is yes. If $\Gamma$ is a set of propositional formulas, then there does exist a decision procedure for the satisfiability of $\Gamma$. One of the two procedures "return True" and "return False" works. What the question must mean is "Does there exist a procedure that determines satisfiability for every $\Gamma$?". And now the question arises of what the input to that procedure would be.

Comment: I actually know very little about decidability; I'm working through a book on propositional calculus and decidability was just mentioned in passing. So I guess that may be why my question is confusing. I'll try to clear things up: I'm asking whether or not there is an algorithm that can take an infinite set of propositional formulas and, after a finite number of steps, tell me whether or not that set is satisfiable. I've worked out that there is an algorithm that will return No after a finite number of steps if $\Gamma$ unsatisfiable, but will never halt if it satisfiable.

Comment: So now I'm looking for the other half (if there is one): an algorithm that will return Yes after a finite number of steps if $\Gamma$ is satisfiable, but may never halt if it is unsatisfiable. If I have this, then I will have an algorithm that will give me either Yes or No after a finite number of steps.

Comment: Again: How can you input an infinite set of formulas to an algorithm? Surely this makes no sense unless $\Gamma$ is recursive?

Comment: Can you take a look at my edit and tell me if this algorithm makes sense?

Comment: Given $\Gamma$, how does that algorithm determine what $\Delta_1$ is?

Comment: Well I guess since $\Gamma$ is countable, $\Delta_1$ can simply be the first element of $\Gamma$, $\Delta_2$ can be the first two elements of $\Gamma$, and so on. Since the compactness theorem says that if $\Gamma$ unsatisfiable, then there is a finite subset of $\Gamma$ that is unsatisfiable; this finite subset must be embedded in one of the $\Delta_i 's$ so I think it would work.

Comment: A countable set per se does not have a first element. A "counted" set has a first element - we need a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\Gamma$. In any case, if the algorithm knows nothing about $\Gamma$ except what it learns by inspecting the elements one at a time it can't possibly know $\Gamma$ is consistent in finitely many steps - how can it know that the next element is not "not P", where P is a previous element?

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: the standard way to send an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ as an input to an algorithm is to use the set as an oracle, and treat the algorithm as an oracle computation. You must have seen this - oracle computation is the bread and butter of computability theory. Also, since the set of all formulas is countable, we would normally assume that the formulas are already arranged in one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$, so we can ask about the "first" one, the "second" one, etc.

Comment: @Carl: your semidecision procedure is correct.

Comment: @CarlMummert No, I know nothing whatever about computability theory. I've been wondering when someone who knew what he was talking about wuold step in...

Comment: Reporting as ordered...  So the idea is, you first modify the programming language with a new instruction, which is a "query". Then, when you run  the program, you have to pick an oracle to run it with. The oracle is not part of the program - the program is still finite and in all other respects like a normal program - but when it runs you answer the "query" instruction with the oracle, which the program sees like a black box. In this way, you can look at programs that can take an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{N}$ as input. ...

Comment: ... Since the program can also take an arbitrary natural number as input,  and return a natural as output, this allows us to compute functions from $P(\mathbb{N}) \times \mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, or by coding methods to compute functions from $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$. This kind of computability allows us to study the computability of a much larger class of problems, such as the one here. @David C. Ullrich

Comment: @CarlMummert Thanks. I misled you regarding my ignorance, sorry - I did have a pretty good idea that an oracle was as you say, what I didn't know was that this was something that one would naturally assume one was talking about in a question like the OP's. (Since it's not the only possibility. One could send a recursive set to an algorithm as a few lines of code - for no reason but ignorance I assumed that was sort of the default.) Thanks.

Comment: That would be a less natural reading, for a computability theorist. But your instinct in a comment above was right in either case, and the answer I wrote can be adapted to show that even in that more limited sense the problem still has no computable solution, because the set $\Gamma_e$ that is constructed is always computable. @David C. Ullrich

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a common exercise, and the answer is "no". There is no algorithmic method that takes a set $\Gamma$ of propositional formulas, in the variables $A$ and $B$, and tells whether the set is satisfiable. Here the method would use the set of formulas as an oracle, meaning that it can ask questions of the form "is this formula in the set?". The method would need to return a correct value "satisfiable" or "unsatisfiable" for every set of formulas.

The proof that there is no such method is by contradiction, using a diagonalization. Given the method, $e$, we can make a set of formulas $\Gamma_e$ that is satisfiable if and only if method $e$ says that $\Gamma_e$ is not satisfiable.

Begin by putting $\lnot A$ into $\Gamma_e$, along with all the formulas $B$, $B\land B$, $B \land B\land B$, etc. Call that set of formulas $S_e$. Now, we begin to algorithmically simulate what method $e$ would do if we ran it on $S_e$. By assumption, method $e$ will eventually halt and say "satisfiable" or "unsatisfiable". By simulating it long enough, we can tell which of these happens. If method $e$ says $S_e$ is "unsatisfiable", we let $\Gamma_e = S_e$, and method $e$ is wrong, because $S_e$ is satisfiable.

If method $e$ says that $S_e$ is satisfiable, we look at all the formulas that method $e$ actually looked at when making that determination. We can form this list effectively, by simulating method $e$ until it halts. There can only be finitely many such formulas that it looks at, because it only runs finitely many steps before halting. So we can find a formula $\phi \equiv B \land B \land \cdots \land B \land A$ that method $e$ never looked at when we ran it. We now let $\Gamma_e = S_e \cup \{\phi\}$.  Then $\Gamma_e$ is a computable set of formulas, and method $e$ will say that $\Gamma_e$ is satisfiable, although it is not.   (Although this is not vital to the proof, there is actually a single algorithm that computes $\Gamma_e$ given any input $e$).

We can do a similar thing with just *one* variable, actually. The important point is that, even with just one variable, there are an infinite number of possible propositional formulas, e.g. $A$, $A \land A$, $A \land A \land A$, ...

Comment: I put off reading this until I had a little time, assuming it was going to be all complicated and confusing. Turned out to be perfectly simple and clear. (I'm wondering why you didn't do it for just one variable instead of doing it for two variables and making that comment at the end. The result for just one variable seems more striking, and if I'm not missing anything it's just as simple - start with $A$, $A\land A$,..., and if the machine says that's satisfiable tack on something of the form $A\land\dots\land A\land \lnot A$. ??? )

Comment: The argument is really just a formalization of the idea you had in a comment, which is that the program has no way to tell what formula will be the "next" one in the set. I think that doing just using one variable might be a little harder pedagogically, and of course once someone sees how to do it with A and B then it is easy to see how to do it with just A.